# R markdown: print selected entries of a data.table or matrix in colour

Tags: r, matrix, colors, data.table, r-markdown

I have a data.table like this:

```
my.data.table <- data.table(a = c(1,-2),
                            b = c(-3,4))
```

Using R markdown to PDF (latex), how can I print `my.data.table` so that all the negative numbers are printed in red, while the positive ones and column headers stay black? An analogous solution for a matrix would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `kableExtra` solution, following the [official documentation](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf):

````
---
title: "kableExtra with cell_spec"
author: "bttomio"
date: "3/26/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
library(data.table)
```

# data.table

```{r echo=F}
my.data.table <- data.table(a = c(1,-2),
                            b = c(-3,4))

my.data.table$a <- cell_spec(my.data.table$a, 
                            color = ifelse(my.data.table$a>0, "black", "red"))

my.data.table$b <- cell_spec(my.data.table$b, 
                            color = ifelse(my.data.table$b>0, "black", "red"))

kbl(my.data.table, 'latex', booktabs = T, escape = F)
```

# matrix

```{r echo=F}
my.data.table <- matrix(c(1,-2,-3,4), nrow = 2,
                        dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("a", "b")))

my.data.table[,1] <- cell_spec(my.data.table[,1], 
                            color = ifelse(my.data.table[,1]>0, "black", "red"))

my.data.table[,2] <- cell_spec(my.data.table[,2], 
                            color = ifelse(my.data.table[,2]>0, "black", "red"))

kbl(my.data.table, 'latex', booktabs = T, escape = F)
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I get some error messages and don't have time for debugging at the moment. I will get back to this once I have time again.